# In ExtJs 6.0 Using Rest Proxy Can't get the proper Id to put in a Httl URL

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, proxy

#### My model

```
Ext.define('Movie.model.MovieModel', {
    extend: 'Movie.model.Base',

    fields: [
        { name: 'Movie_id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Movie_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Movie_details', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Movie_release', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'Movie_url', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Movie_price', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Rent_day', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

#### My Stores With URL

```
Ext.define('Movie.store.MovieStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.movie',
    storeId: 'movieStore',
    model: 'Movie.model.MovieModel',
    Fields: ['Movie_id', 'Movie_name', 'Movie_details', 'Movie_release', 'Movie_url', 'Movie_price'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
       url:'/api/Movies',
      disableCaching: true,
       useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        api: {
          create: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/AddMovie',
            read: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/GetMovie',
            update: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/EditMovie',
            destroy: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/DeleteMovie'
        },
        reader:{
          type:'json',
          headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }            
      },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false,
           
        }
        
    }, autoLoad: true

});
```

#### Controller to delete record

```
 var data = store.findRecord('Movie_name', name);
                var id = data.get('Movie_id');
            store.remove(store.findRecord('Movie_id',id,0,false,false,false));
            store.sync();
```

#### In my web API

```
  [Route("Movies/DeleteMovie/{id}")]
        [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Delete", "Post","Get")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpDelete]

   
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteMovie(int id)

        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            Movie movie = db.Movie.Find(id);
           

            db.Movie.Remove(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(movie);
        }
```

#### Errors

But all the methods are not working. I get these errors in my `console.log`:

> **`$id`**: 1
> **Message**: The request is invalid.
> **Message Detail**: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter `id` of non-nullable type `System.Int32` for method `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult DeleteMovie(Int32)` in `MovieRentals.Controllers.MoviesController`. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

The URL sending the request from extjs  is
`https://localhost:44369/Movies/DeleteMovie/MovieModel-75?_dc=1682656495712`
instead of `https://localhost:44369/Movies/DeleteMovie/123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Ext JS uses a field named `id` as the unique identifier for a model instance. Since the identifier in your model is called differently (`Movie_id`) ExtJS will add an automatically generated identifier (for example `MovieModel-75`) for each model and passes that in the REST request. This is the same mechanism which is used to add an identifier to phantom records which are created on the client side and do not have an identifier on the server yet.

You can easily set a custom id property to be used with your model. This way you tell Ext JS not the use `id` but a different field.

Simply add this to the model definition:

```
Ext.define('Movie.model.MovieModel', {
    extend: 'Movie.model.Base',
    idProperty: 'Movie_id',
    ...
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it works for you please consider accepting my answer. It can help others with similar question.

Comment: HI ,theres a bug on other table when I applied this method in other table doesnt work the idProperty ignored and send a payload of "delete/ExtModel133-3" something instead of delete/123 , first model works fine but user table not. Please help

Comment: Please share the code if you need help. There should be no difference.

Comment: The Movie Part is working But the User Table not, I repeat those method set a idProperty: 'User_id' and persist: false but not working

Comment: hi I posted an answer containing my codes I reapeat those actions but the users part not works